# ion-infinite-scroll does not work when scrolling both horizontally and vertically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, scroll

Am working on a ionic app which has one page that has got horizontal scroll. I want to use ion-infinite scroll to both vertical and horizontal scroll but it is only working for horizontal scroll right now.

Can anyone temme if I can have infinite scroll for both horizontal scroll and vertical scroll in a same page ?

```
<div>
            <ion-scroll direction="x" class="con-scroll-x" has-bouncing="true">
                <div class="scroll-div">
                    <div class="scroll-div-item" ng-repeat="trips in globalPlaces.result_trip_search">
                        <img  alt="title"   src="img/list-img/1.jpg" />
                        <div class="scroll-item-caption">
                            <div class="caption-rect">
                                <img  alt="title"   src="img/ic_hiker.png" />
                                <span>{{ trips.count_ratio }}</span>                            
                            </div>
                            <div class="scroll-caption-text">
                                <p>Viaje a:</p>
                                <h3 class="title-break">{{ trips.end_city }}</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="scroll-caption-date">
                                <span>{{ trips.start_date }}</span> <img  alt="title"   src="img/ic_date.png" /> <span>{{ trips.end_date }}</span>
                            </div>
                        <div class="comm-user-img">
                            <!-- scroll-cap-user-pics  -->
                                <!--<img  scroll-cap-user-pics alt="title" src="img/list_user1.png" />-->
                                <img  alt="title" src="{{ trips.profile_photo }}" class="comm-global-user-img" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ion-scroll>
        </div>
```

The above code is making some problem in infinite scroll when i scroll vertically. It works good in horizontal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that is [know bug](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3652) in `ionic`, like when you are having `ion-scroll` and `ion-infinite-scroll` in same page ionic not able to fire infinite load.

**Possible solution**

Wrap your `ion-scroll` inside `DIV` and add `ng-if` to that `DIV` and in your controller set `ng-if` model to `true`.

**Example**

**HTML**

```
<div ng-if="PleaseShowMe">
    <ion-scroll direction="x" class="con-scroll-x" has-bouncing="true">
    <---other code--->
    </ion-scroll>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$timeout(function()
{
    $scope.PleaseShowMe = true;
},50);
```

**Note:** Even this way you can not achieve horizontal scroll, but what you can do it while scrolling vertical you can append data to horizontal scroll.

Comment: @jalajsharma : Always welcome, glad that it worked for you.  But please read the *Note* part too.